# Can't get an object deletion - ?csrfmiddlewaretoken= appears at the end of the current URL in the urlbar (django)

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-csrf, django-generic-views, csrf-token

I am building a simple social network in django.

In the "home" of my social, I have the list of all posts published by all users, with author and publishing date. Under each post of the logged user, a "delete" button appears. If the user clicks on it, it returns a specific view of that post, with a message "do you really wish to delete this post?" and two buttons to confirm or cancel the post deletion.

However, as I click on button "confirm deletion", the page reloads to the same point, and nothing changes except for the fact that

> ?csrfmiddlewaretoken=--random-sequence--

appears at the end of the current url in the urlbar.

What am I missing?

Here is my template:

```
<h3>Do you want to delete this post?</h3>

<div class="posts">
    {% include "posts/_post.html" with post=object hide_delete=True %}
</div>

<form class="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">

    <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-simple btn-large btn-default">Cancel</a>

</form>
```

and my DeletePost view based on `generic.DeleteView`:

```
class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):

    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:all')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id = self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request,'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have

```
<form class="POST">
```

It should be

```
<form method="POST">
```

When method is missing, the browser does a GET request by default, so you see the form values in the URL querystring.